# How can i lock toolkit:LongListMultiSelector in selection mode?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-toolkit

I've implemented a list of friends in my app by using `toolkit:LongListMultiSelector`, and by default I've set it to show the boxes for checking friends (enabled selection mode).
But if you select someone, and deselect the checkboxes disappears, and to get them visiable again you have to weirdly tap to the left of the list item, where the box should have been.

I've hacked it so it always stays up by listening to the event `IsSelectionEnabledChanged` and in that event I'm always forcing enabling: `ListOfFriends.IsSelectionEnabled = true;`

Is'nt there a better way to *always* keep selection enabled? My hack causes the list to actually flicker, it closes the list for 20ms, but then the event kicks in and forces the list to to enable selection again.

Answer (score 7):

you can easily achieve this via

```
 ListOfFriends.EnforceIsSelectionEnabled=true;
```